# QGIS - Link derived coordinates to an attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, coordinates, virtual-field, link

How can I link a field of derived coordinates and attributes to an attribute table? It cannot be copied manually, many lines (100,000).

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what are your exact need ? (like witch derived coordinates and attributes you want to add to the attribute table and on witch layer). from your picture it seem that using the field calculator with simple geometric function should work

Comment: Exactly as you type, the data generated when drawing the line at the top is copied to the prepared fields of the attribute table at the bottom. But I'm a beginner, so I don't know how. Will you help me?

Comment: To get the length you may use the field calculator (see : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=field%20calculator#using-the-field-calculator) with "$length" (ellipsoidal length) or "length($geometry)" (Cartesian length) but for the x/y coordinate you need to tell us witch coordinate you want to get as a line has not just one xy coordinate (the identify tool return the coordinate of the closest point on the line and the coordinate of the closest vertex those may not be what you need)